# I performed Column transformer on my data to encode categorical features and Scale numeric features. The result combined all transformations in 1 coln

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn

All the output transformations got combined into one column:
[image: Output]

Shape of my data frame was `(445132, 34)`
it got reduced to `(445132, 1)`

categorical object contains all categorical columns except "General health"
numerical contains all numerical columns

The following is my code:

```py
trans = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ("encoder", OrdinalEncoder(categories=[["Excellent","Very good","Good","Fair","Poor"]]), ["GeneralHealth"]),
    ("encoder1", OneHotEncoder(drop="first"), categorical),
    ("scaler", StandardScaler(), numerical)
], remainder="passthrough")

f_transformed = trans.fit_transform(f)

transformed_data = pd.DataFrame(f_transformed, columns=trans.get_feature_names_out())

transformed_data.head(4)
```

I also tried to set `verbose_feature_names_out=False` in `ColumnTransformer()`, but it did not change not anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are using `sklearn` version `1.2` or newer, can you please try the following? I just want to rule out the cause of the issue is transforming from `numpy` array to `pandas` `DataFrame`.

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder, OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler

# Define the transformer
trans = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ("encoder", OrdinalEncoder(categories=[["Excellent", "Very good", "Good", "Fair", "Poor"]]), ["GeneralHealth"]),
    ("encoder1", OneHotEncoder(drop="first"), categorical),
    ("scaler", StandardScaler(), numerical)
], remainder="passthrough")

# Set the output of the transformer to a pandas DataFrame
trans.set_output(transform="pandas")

# Fit and transform the data
f_transformed = trans.fit_transform(f)

# Now f_transformed should be a DataFrame with the appropriate column names
transformed_data = f_transformed

# Display the first few rows of the DataFrame
print(transformed_data.head(4))
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Also if possible could you tell me what was wrong with code? Like why did the shape reduce after transformation?

Comment: @SiddhantHardikar Glad to hear that it worked! In that case I'd appreciate if you [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). I could dig deeper into the reason for the error if I had a [reprex]